# Figure out this algorithm by analyzing the sequence of numbers generated

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence, algorithm

You are given a function *f* that, using an algorithm (that uses an old method), performs a calculation on *four* distinct values _ and generates a sequence of *ten* numbers.

Now, your task is to figure out how the algorithm works based on the outputs received for a set of inputs.

*Inputs and Outputs:*

```
f([1, 1, 1, 1])=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
f([2, 2, 2, 2])=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
f([3, 3, 3, 3])=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
f([4, 4, 4, 4])=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
f([5, 5, 5, 5])=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
f([6, 6, 6, 6])=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
f([8, 8, 8, 8])=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
f([7, 7, 7, 7])=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
f([9, 9, 9, 9])=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
f([1, 2, 3, 6])=[5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2]
f([2, 3, 6, 5])=[2, 4, 1, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 0]
f([4, 1, 7, 9])=[2, 6, 1, 5, 0, 4, 8, 3, 7, 2]
f([5, 2, 6, 7])=[2, 0, 5, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2, 0, 5]
f([8, 1, 3, 2])=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
f([4, 6, 5, 8])=[5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1]
f([1, 7, 9, 44])=[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
f([1, 6, 47, 2])=[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
f([45, 87, 95, 68])=[66, 43, 20, 65, 42, 19, 64, 41, 18, 63]
f([335, 66, 48, 97])=[42, 86, 33, 77, 24, 68, 15, 59, 6, 50]
f([48, 796, 548, 1])=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
f([8794, 35, 3, 3])=[2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
f([89, 554, 665, 7])=[5, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2, 0, 5, 3, 1]
f([54, 89, 32, 67])=[14, 1, 55, 42, 29, 16, 3, 57, 44, 31]
f([21, 65, 78, 49])=[22, 43, 15, 36, 8, 29, 1, 22, 43, 15]
f([3, 5, 11, 9])=[8, 2, 5, 8, 2, 5, 8, 2, 5, 8]
f([37, 42, 13, 128])=[31, 68, 105, 14, 51, 88, 125, 34, 71, 108]
f([48, 76, 2, 34])=[12, 26, 6, 20, 0, 14, 28, 8, 22, 2]
f([94, 57, 62, 111])=[92, 75, 58, 41, 24, 7, 101, 84, 67, 50]
f([111, 222, 333, 664])=[407, 518, 629, 76, 187, 298, 409, 520, 631, 78]
f([795, 1, 45, 3333])=[840, 1635, 2430, 3225, 687, 1482, 2277, 3072, 534, 1329]
f([897, 4, 6, 2])=[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
f([68, 749, 44, 88])=[24, 4, 72, 52, 32, 12, 80, 60, 40, 20]
f([78946, 6656, 4, 10])=[0, 6, 2, 8, 4, 0, 6, 2, 8, 4]
f([8, 1, 222, 77])=[76, 7, 15, 23, 31, 39, 47, 55, 63, 71]
f([1, 2, 3, 99999])=[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Comment: Could you potentially edit in a more descriptive title?

Comment: @Emrakul♦ i have edited it. Thank u for pointing it for me. I hope its better now. And more info cant be provided in the title than this or else they will be spoilers. Thanx again =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's call $A,B,C,D$ the parameters of the function.
The first term of the sequence is

> $((A\times B)+C)$mod $D$

Each consequent term is obtained  from the previous this way:

> Add $A$ then modulo $D$

The $n$th term of the sequence can be expressed as:

> $(A\times (B+n)+C)mod\ D$

If you need a proof of the equivalence of the two definitions, just ask in the comments.

**Example:**

```
f([89, 554, 665, 7])=[5, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2, 0, 5, 3, 1]
```

The first term is

> $(89\times 554+665) mod\ 7 =5$

The second is

> $(5+89)mod\ 7=3$

And the $n$th is

> $(89\times (554+n)+665)mod\ 7$

Comment: I think you can simplify by saying all terms are `((A x (B + n)) + C) mod D`, where *n* is the position in the series (0-indexed).

Comment: Thanks, it can easily proven that the two formula are equivalent, but your is easier. I will edit asap

Answer (score 3):

This function delivers

> an arithmetic sequence.

The first element of the parameter is

> the number to add on each iteration.

The second element of the parameter is

> the initial value of our iterator.

The third element of the parameter is

> the initial offset of the sequence.

The fourth element of the parameter is

> the modulus.

The function is described in code as:

> ```
> def f(x):
>   r = []
>   for i in range(x[1],x[1]+10):
>     r += [(x[2] + (i*x[0]))%x[3]]
>   return r
> ```

Comment: The first and fourth arguments seem correct, that's what I was thinking too. The 2nd and 3rd are totally wrong, check this:
f([2, 3, 6, 5])=[2, 4, 1, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 0]